# Gunicorn Import by filename is not supported (module)

Tags: python, containers, gunicorn

I have newly created a container ubuntu and installed the required packages in the virtual environment. Then I have executed the pre-existing python service code by python path/to/my/file/X.py (in virualenv) it's working fine. So I have executed with gunicorn as gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 path/to/my/file/X:app (in virualenv) but I'm getting the following error

```
2015-11-11 16:38:08 [19118] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 17.5
2015-11-11 16:38:08 [19118] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:444 (19118)
2015-11-11 16:38:08 [19118] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2015-11-11 16:38:08 [19123] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 19123
2015-11-11 16:38:08 [19123] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 473, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 100, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 115, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 33, in load
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 362, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 473, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 100, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 115, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 33, in load
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 362, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.
2015-11-11 16:38:08 [19123] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 19123)
2015-11-11 16:38:09 [19118] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
```

Can anyone help me fix the `ImportError: Import by filename is not supported`. Why it is coming? I have implemented gunicorn in other server, it is working fine there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's just like the error says: you can't refer to Python modules by file path, you must refer to it by dotted module path starting at a directory that is in PYTHONPATH.

```
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 path.inside.virtualenv.X:app
```

Comment: Thanks for your immediate reply, But i'm getting same error after changed ' File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 362, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named var.www.o9_prod.dev.myprojectenv.__init__:app'  .  i have one more doubt in this its taking the path as '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn' but my virtual environment path is 'var/www/prod/myvirtualenv/bin' . so do i'm getting this error because of this ?

Comment: That's not the same error. And you didn't do what I said: the path must be from the root of the virtualenv.

Comment: oh sorry, so can you please check is this a right command to start gunicorn "gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 /var/www/prod/myvirtualenv.__init__:app" and if i'm mistaken please correct me

Comment: No. How can I make this clearer? Use a *module path*. Is your "app" object really inside `__init__.py` in the root of your virtualenv? That is an odd place to put it; place it inside a properly named module like "mysite.py" then do `gunicorn mysite:app`.

Comment: gunicorn "gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 /var/www/prod/myvirtualenv.__init__:app" and if i'm mistaken please correct me. for better understanding my python file is in /var/www/prod/__init__.py and vitualenv in /var/www/prod/myvirtualenv/bin

Comment: i have checked it app object is in __init__.py.

Answer (score 5):

I faced very same issue, I got it worked using `--chdir /path/to/project`

```
gunicorn -b :5000 --chdir /path/to/project X:app
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is perfect because the `wsgi` file I want Gunicorn to serve is inside a filepath that already contains `.` (/python2.7/) so the dotted module path was failing. Thanks.

Comment: great, Glad this helped

Answer (score 0):

Just for the googlers, I also had this error when i accidentally ran my application using gunicorn -paste instead of gunicorn --paste. gunicorn did not error, but the api.ini was not found and it threw the 'Import by filename is not supported' error.